# What data structure is used to implement the dynamic memory allocation heap?

Tags: data-structures, memory-management, heap-memory

I always assumed a [heap (data structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) is used to implement a [heap (dynamic memory allocation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation#Dynamic_memory_allocation), but I've been told I'm wrong.

How are heaps (for example, the one implemented by typical `malloc` routines, or by Windows's `HeapCreate`, etc.) implemented, typically? What data structures do they use?

#### What I'm *not* asking:

While searching online, I've seen ***tons*** of descriptions of how to implement heaps *with severe restrictions*.
To name a few, I've seen lots of descriptions of how to implement:

- Heaps that never release memory back to the OS (!)
- Heaps that only give reasonable performance on small, similarly-sized blocks
- Heaps that only give reasonable performance for large, contiguous blocks
- etc.

And it's funny, they all avoid the harder question:
How are "normal", general-purpose heaps (like the one behind `malloc`, `HeapCreate`) implemented?

What data structures (and perhaps algorithms) do they use?

Comment: Yes the two kind of heap are different.  To learn about dynamic memory allocation google for dlmalloc (used by glibc) or tcmalloc (used by google).

Comment: @brianbeuning: Will take a look at dlmalloc, thanks. But [TCMalloc currently does not return any memory to the system](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes. Most (all?) Unix based mallocs do not ever return memory to the system.

Comment: I don't think the C++ and C tags are appropriate here, but I'm having trouble thinking of better ones.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Same trouble I was having ;)

Comment: @BillyONeal: Wait really? Is Linux an exception? Because I could swear I've never seen a program on Linux whose memory usage has only ever gone up, but perhaps I've just been ignorant...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Depends on what is meant by "memory usage". There are loads of different ways to measure that.

Comment: Fragmentation makes returning memory to the system extremely difficult for many workloads. Figuring out ways to fight fragmentation is one of the larger points of variation among modern allocators. That, and concurrency.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Yup -- you tell me how to measure it, I'll measure it for you. :P I could swear I've never seen *any* memory-related statistic on Linux that monotonously goes up.

Comment: Yeah; I fixed up my answer below upon discovering that dlmalloc attempts to do this.

Comment: I suggested tcmalloc because I recently ran a test using different allocators with some work software.  TCmalloc was the only allocator to use significantly less CPU time and less total memory allocated than the rest.

Comment: For completely different take on this topic check out the Boehm conservative garbage collecting allocator.

Comment: Recent versions of dlmalloc have a cool feature called mspaces.  You use malloc() and free() on an mspace, or you can delete the mspace and free all memory allocated in the mspace.  We are using this in our application server so each web session gets its own mspace.  The mspace greatly improves page and cache locality, and if our code has any memory leak bug deleting the mspace fixes the leak.  Our sessions uses one thread so mspaces can help the multi-threading issues recent allocators address.

Answer (score 14):

Allocators tend to be quite complex and often differ significantly in how they're implemented.

You can't really describe them in terms of one common data structure or algorithm, but there are some common themes:

1. Memory is taken from the system in large chunks -- often megabytes at a time.
2. These chunks are then split up into various smaller chunks as you perform allocations. Not exactly the same size as you allocate, but usually in certain ranges (200-250 bytes, 251-500 bytes, etc.).  Sometimes this is multi-tiered, where you'd have an additional layer of "medium chunks" which come before your actual requests.
3. Controlling which "large chunk" to break a piece off of is a very difficult and important thing to do -- this greatly affects memory fragmentation.
4. One or more free pools (aka "free list", "memory pool", "lookaside list") are maintained for each of these ranges. Sometimes even thread-local pools. This can greatly speed up a pattern of allocating/deallocating many objects of similar size.
5. Large allocations are treated a bit differently so as to not waste a lot of RAM and not be pooled quite so much if at all.

If you wanted to check out some source code, [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/) is a modern high-performance allocator and should be representative in complexity of other common ones. [TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) is another common general-purpose allocator, and their website goes into all the gory implementation details. Intel's [Thread Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) has an allocator built specifically for high concurrency.

One interesting difference can be seen between Windows and *nix. In *nix, the allocator has very low-level control over the address space an app uses. In Windows, you basically have a course-grained, slow allocator `VirtualAlloc` to base your own allocator off of.

This results in *nix-compatible allocators typically directly giving you an `malloc`/`free` implementation where it's assumed you'll only use one allocator for everything (otherwise they'd trample each-other), while Windows-specific allocators provide additional functions, leaving `malloc`/`free` alone, and can be used in harmony (for instance, you can use HeapCreate to make private heaps which can work alongside others).

In practice, this trade in flexibility gives *nix allocators a small leg up performance-wise. It's very rare to see an app intentionally use multiple heaps on Windows -- mostly it's by accident due to different DLLs using different runtimes which each have their own `malloc`/`free`, and can cause a lot of headaches if you're not diligent in tracking which heap some memory came from.

Comment: Okay, so (to summarize) they maintain pools of different sizes, instead of making everything variable-sized... interesting, thanks. +1

Comment: One thing I don't get: How is `VirtualAlloc` more coarse-grained than whatever *nix systems use?

Comment: Well, I didn't say it is _more_ coarse-grained, but it is, actually -- `VirtualAlloc` forces you to allocate in 64KB (for now.. this may change in the future) chunks, while I believe `sbrk` and `mmap` both operate on (typically) 4KB pages.

Answer (score 6):

Note: The following answer assumes you're using a typical, modern system with virtual memory. The C and C++ standards do not require virtual memory; therefore of course you can't rely on such assumptions on hardware without this feature (e.g. GPUs typically don't have this feature; nor do extremely small hardware like the PIC).

---

This depends on the platform you're using. Heaps can be very complicated beasts; they don't use only a single data structure; and there is no "standard" data structure. Even where the heap code is located is different depending on the platform. For instance, the heap code is typically provided by the C Runtime on Unix boxes; but is typically provided by the operating system on Windows.

1. Yes, this is common on Unix machines; due to the way *nix's underlying APIs and memory model operate. Basically, the standard API to return memory to the operating system on these systems only allows returning memory on the "frontier" between where user memory is allocated and the "hole" in between user memory and system facilities like the stack. (The API in question is [`brk` or `sbrk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbrk)). Instead of returning memory to the operating system, many heaps only try to reuse memory no longer in use by the program proper, and don't try to return memory to the system. This is less common on Windows, because its equivalent to `sbrk` (`VirtualAlloc`) doesn't have this limitation. (But like `sbrk`, it is very expensive and has caveats like only allocating page-sized and page-aligned chunks. So heaps try to call either as rarely as possible)
2. This sounds like a "block allocator", which divides the memory into fixed size chunks, and then just return one of the free chunks. To my (albeit limited) understanding, Windows' `RtlHeap` maintains a number of data structures like this for different known block sizes. (E.g. it'll have one for blocks of size 16, for instance) RtlHeap calls these "lookaside lists".
3. I don't really know of a specific structure that handles this case well. Large blocks are problematic for most allocation systems because they cause fragmentation of the address space.

The best reference I've found discussing the common allocation strategies employed on major platforms is the book [*Secure Coding in C and C++*, by Robert Seacord](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321335724). All of chapter 4 is dedicated to heap data structures (and problems caused when users use said heap systems incorrectly).

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you're trying to say about `sbrk` not being able to release memory and all... What does the hypothetical program have to do with this question?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Basically, the model that \*nix uses is that user dynamic memory is all allocated in the "data segment". Then there's a "hole" of unused memory. And then on top of that there's the stack. (More or less -- which way is up and which way is down depends on platform convention; some memory space is reserved for the operating system; etc.) The way you ask for memory on a \*nix system is to call `sbrk`, which just increases the data segment size into that "unused hole" between user data and the stack and such.

Comment: @Mehrdad: So, yes, a heap algorithm could shrink the size of said data segment. But the circumstances in which it could do so are rare, and detecting the case where all memory between <some address> and the current end of the data segment is being unused would be very expensive to do in `free`. So most (all?) allocators don't do it.

Comment: Right, and then you can just decrease the data segment size just the same, so where is the problem exactly? Is this not done in practice? (If so, then that means if I open up a utility like `top` I should never see memory usage go down, right?)

Comment: @Mehrdad: For instance, you have a program that allocates memory of size 100MB with `sbrk`. Then you allocate memory of size 1MB with `sbrk`. Then the size 100MB is deallocated. There isn't a way to return that back to the system; because that 1MB is further out keeping the size of the data segment large. There isn't a way to return that memory in the middle. Since this is a very common bit to run in to, and since detecting when the entire end of the data section is free is expensive, most `malloc`s don't do it.

Comment: I see what you're saying, that it can only happen if the free space is at the very end. I'm just surprised that you say this is so rare... let me run a Linux system once to see it with my own eyes, because I'm really surprised I've never seen it before! :)

Comment: Okay, I just fired up an Ubuntu VM, and I clearly see the "Resident Memory" column of Firefox going up and down. So what's up with that?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Hmm.. Looking at the docs for `dlmalloc`, it appears that it does attempt to return data back to the system. But of course the caveats I mentioned above apply.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Some allocators might use the newer and less standard API `mmap` for large (<1MB) allocations, which gets rid of a large part of this too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20826/discussion-between-billy-oneal-and-mehrdad)